# Magento 2 cannot login admin because form key invalid

Tags: cookies, magento2

I'm in a brain-breaking problem here. I've created a nice Magento 2.1.7 installation with two websites (two stores, two domains) and somehow after a while we are unable to login the backend of Magento.

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Now, after trying a few options, still no success. Checked core_config_data, edit max_input_vars, nothing works. The strange thing is, on the front it's still possible to checkout and do your shopping.

Anyway, I'm stumped here. Why is this happening, and how can this be fixed. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you changed your database with different magento2 database

Comment: I'm in the middle of creating a clean install with all modules in it, hoping if I switch database it will fall in place. While comparing the two, I've noticed that web/cookie/cookie_domain is not even created in core_config_data in the fresh install. I'm using subdomains for both main domains and it's working fine. Made a copy of the current (live) db, and I'm currently comparing it to the fresh db install with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

I often get this error, clearing the cookies for that site, then opening the admin panel in a new tab will resolve this.
You can recreate this error message if you double click the login button after filling out your login information.

Here are a few other reasons you may experience this issue

1. The form key inputs are outside of the form, you should check the html on the admin panel to check these inputs and exists and have correct values
2. Make sure the link you use to get to the admin page does not already have a form key in the url

Does this issue generate anything in var/log/system.log ?

Comment: Eventually i've done something completely different - I found out that something went very wrong with cookies/caching and http/https switching. What I've done, step by step, is added to this story.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, nothing helped, but what did the trick was creating a new install, setup this new install with all necessary modules (fortunately there were only four), configure the fresh installment like the old one (long live GitHub) and compare your fresh installation to the old one in the database table core_config_data. Basically reproduce your entire setup without any products in it, but just create your stores and categories.

If you spot any differences between the new installment and the old one in the core_config_data, edit them in the old one to be the same as your new one.

Next, edit your env.php with the database credentials to the old database which you've compared and edited.

And the last step, recompile, flush/clean cache and reindex.

Oh, and word of advice, if you're going to use https for your store, setup magento on https. I think something went very wrong when we've changed the base url's from insecure to secure.